# Why my React native app after installing react navigation v5 it doesn't updating the modified code in the bundle?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

here is my App.js code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Home from './Root/Home'
import Profile from './Root/Profile'

import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const Rootstack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: Home,`enter code here`
  Profile: Profile,
})
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Rootstack/>
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

here is one of my other screen code :

```
import React , {Component} from 'react';
import { text,TextInput, button, view,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

export default class RegisterPage extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
        <view style = {styles.container}>
          <view style = {styles.registerform}>

          <TextInput style = {styles.input}
              placeholder="Enter yor name"
              returnKeyType="next"
              onsubmitEditing = {()=> this.passwordInput.focus()}
            
              />

          <TextInput style = {styles.input}
              placeholder="Enter your Email"
              returnKeyType="Next"
              onsubmitEditing = {()=> this.passwordInput.focus()}
              keyboardType="Email-Adress"
              autoCapitalize= "none"
              autoCorrect = {false}
              ref = {(input)=> this.emailinput.focus()}
              />
           
              <TextInput style = {styles.input}
              placeholder="Enter password"
              returnKeyType="Go"
              secureTextEntry
              ref = {(input)=> this.passwordInput= input}
              />

              <TouchableOpacity style= {styles.buttoncontainer} onPress ={ () => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
                <text style={styles.buttoncText}> Sign Up</text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </view>
        </view>
    );
  }
}
```

here is what it displaying on my bundle screen after i refresh the code from vscode:

[the bundle result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMmOS.png)

Please guys I really need help with this i've been trying this for almost 2 weeks and I can't get it right, when I create my react native app and run the default App.js on the bundle it display the message and if I change the text it refresh but as soon as I install react navigation v5 and add screen than nothing shows, than it goes blank like the picture that I attach please what can I do to solve this issue thanks.

here is what i install for navigations stack : npm install --save react-navigation stack.
npm install @react-navigation/native.
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view.
NB: am using window 10

Comment: You installed `react-navigation v5`, but you are using `react-navigation v4`. I don't know it's spelling mistake or you other but you have to import `View` and `Text` from 'react-native`, not `text` and `view`. And also please add your `Home` screen code because that screen will be the first screen as navigation.

Answer (score 0):

**Sometimes** **its** **

> node server

error

**Steps you can try**

> kill the node server
>
> remove node_modules
>
> install node_modules again
>
> re-run your project